# VB.net (WPF system). How to open and close the same window several times?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

(WPF system). How to open and close the same window several times?
The code below does not work. I can only open the "About" window once.
I do not know how to avoid this mistake. Could you help me ? Thank you.

```
'Window Main

Class MainWindow
    Dim WindowAbout As FormAbout = New FormAbout
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        WindowAbout.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

--------

'Window About

Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FormAbout
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching, here is the answer: add WindowAbout = New FormAbout

```
'Window Main

Class MainWindow
    Dim WindowAbout As FormAbout = New FormAbout
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        WindowAbout = New FormAbout
        WindowAbout.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

--------

'Window About

Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FormAbout
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The `WindowAbout` field in your class serves no real purpose (you are always overwriting it on each click), consider making it a local variable in the `Button_Click` method.

Comment: (WindowAbout = New FormAbout). This code works well. Is the method you are proposing simpler? Can you write this line of code?

Comment: Yes, it works. The more or less unused field is more of an estethical problem. I would remove the field `WindowAbout` and instead use a local valiable in the Button_Click method, like `Dim WindowAbout As FormAbout = New FormAbout` (instead of `WindowAbout = New FormAbout`).

Comment: Yes, you are right, your remark is relevant. This formula is more rational. I will follow your advice. Thank you for expressing this observation.